# i am fetching the data from database and display in magento admin grid, and the grid display blank

Tags: magento2, database, admin, grid, quote

I have tried all of my thinking, I don't understand why the grid displays a blank

Controller

```
namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Controller\Adminhtml\Bulkquote;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;

use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

use StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\RequestQuoteFactory; 

use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Index extends Action

{

protected $_resultPageFactory;
protected $_requestQuoteFactory;
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    RequestQuoteFactory $requestQuoteFactory, 
    Registry $registry
) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_requestQuoteFactory = $requestQuoteFactory;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Bulk Quotes'));

    return $resultPage;
}
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
```

}`

di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <virtualType name="RequestQuoteGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">RequestQuoteGridFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
 </virtualType>
    
 <virtualType name="RequestQuoteGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
 </virtualType>

<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="StateDrives_RequestQuote::menu" title="Bulk Quote" module="StateDrives_RequestQuote" sortOrder="100" resource="StateDrives_RequestQuote::requestquote"/>
    <add id="StateDrives_RequestQuote::requestquote" title="Bulk Quote" module="StateDrives_RequestQuote" sortOrder="20" action="statesrives_requestquote/bulkquote/index" resource="StateDrives_RequestQuote::statesrives_requestquote_requestquote" parent="StateDrives_RequestQuote::menu"/>
</menu>
```

model

```
namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class RequestQuote extends AbstractModel
{
 protected function _construct()
 {
     $this- 
>_init('StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote');
 }
}
```

ResourceModel

```
namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class RequestQuote extends AbstractDb
 {
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
)
{
    parent::__construct($context);
}
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('request_for_bulkquote', 'entity_id');
 }
}
```

Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote

```
 namespace 
 StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote;

  use 
  Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\ 
  AbstractCollection;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
  {
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'request_for_bulkquote';

  protected function _construct()
 { 
    $this->_init(
        \StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\RequestQuote::class
\StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote::class
    );
  }
}
```

view/adminhtml/layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="styles"/>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="request_for_bulkquote_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

ui_component

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_columns</item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote\Grid\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_columns</item>
                </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_columns</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>
</container>
<columns name="request_for_bulkquote_columns" class ="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ENTITY ID</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="full_name" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">FULL NAME</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="email" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">EMAIL</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="phone" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">PHONE</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="quantity" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">QUANTITY</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="how_soon_do_you_need_it" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">How soon do you need it</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
    <column name="company_name" >
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">COMPANY NAME</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
</columns>
```

db_schema.xml

```
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
<table name="request_for_bulkquote" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="State Drives Request Quote Table">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity ID"/>
    <column xsi:type="text" name="full_name" nullable="false" comment="Full Name"/>
    <column xsi:type="text" name="email" nullable="false" comment="Email"/>
    <column xsi:type="text" name="phone" nullable="false" comment="Phone"/>
    <column xsi:type="int" name="quantity" nullable="false" comment="Quantity"/>
    <column xsi:type="varchar" name="how_soon_do_you_need_it" comment="How soon do you need it"/>
    <column xsi:type="text" name="company_name" nullable="true" comment="Company Name"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="entity_id"/>
    </constraint>
</table>
```

[image]
please help me to get out of this,I will be thankful to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Please replace the existing module code with the following code.**

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote**

**registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'StateDrives_RequestQuote', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="StateDrives_RequestQuote" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/etc/adminhtml**

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>

        <add id="StateDrives_RequestQuote::menu" title="Bulk Quote" module="StateDrives_RequestQuote" sortOrder="100" resource="StateDrives_RequestQuote::requestquote"/>

        <add id="StateDrives_RequestQuote::requestquote" title="Bulk Quote" module="StateDrives_RequestQuote" sortOrder="20" action="statesrives_requestquote/bulkquote/index" resource="StateDrives_RequestQuote::statesrives_requestquote_requestquote" parent="StateDrives_RequestQuote::menu"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/etc/adminhtml**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="statesrives_requestquote" frontName="statesrives_requestquote">
            <module name="StateDrives_RequestQuote" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="request_for_bulkquote" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="State Drives Request Quote Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Entity ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="full_name" nullable="false" comment="Full Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="email" nullable="false" comment="Email"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="phone" nullable="false" comment="Phone"/>
        <column xsi:type="int" name="quantity" nullable="false" comment="Quantity"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="how_soon_do_you_need_it" comment="How soon do you need it"/>
        <column xsi:type="text" name="company_name" nullable="true" comment="Company Name"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="entity_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote\RequestQuote\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote\RequestQuote\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/Controller/Adminhtml/Bulkquote**

**Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Controller\Adminhtml\Bulkquote;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Registry $registry
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Bulk Quotes'));

        return $resultPage;
    }

}
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/Model**

**RequestQuote.php**

```
<?php

namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model;

class RequestQuote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote');
    }
}
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/Model/ResourceModel**

**RequestQuote.php**

```
<?php

namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel;

class RequestQuote extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('request_for_bulkquote', 'entity_id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/Model/ResourceModel/RequestQuote**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php

namespace StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'entity_id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'request_for_bulkquote';

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            'StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\RequestQuote',
            'StateDrives\RequestQuote\Model\ResourceModel\RequestQuote'
        );
    }
}
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/view/adminhtml/layout**

**statesrives_requestquote_bulkquote_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="request_for_bulkquote_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/StateDrives/RequestQuote/view/adminhtml/ui_component**

**request_for_bulkquote_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <container name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_listing.request_for_bulkquote_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
    <columns name="request_for_bulkquote_columns" class ="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ENTITY ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="full_name" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">FULL NAME</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">EMAIL</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="phone" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">PHONE</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="quantity" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">QUANTITY</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="how_soon_do_you_need_it" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">How soon do you need it</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="company_name" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">COMPANY NAME</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

> **After adding and updating the file, please run the following Magento commands.**

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:s:d -f
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento s:d:c
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento cache:clean
```

**OUTPUT**
[image]

[**Download Module Code**](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/12-JTKEGtxl9ejBzGOl4G2VMOWZRAB9xJ?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Please add proper files with fullpath and filename

For your query, check your listing page filename, admin route name

suppose if your route name is "abbas" then your file name should be abbas_grid_your_listing.xml

abbas = route name

grid = controller folder name

your_listing = index = controller file name

filename should be like **abbas_grid_index.xml**